# C++: Parsing a log with split but one entry can have several lines

Tags: c++, regex, split

I am started to learn C++, and my current project should extend my knowledge in using files, split and finally do a regexp on a varchar string.

The problem:

I have a logfile wich contains data like

```
<date> <time> <username> (<ip:port>) <uuid> - #<id> "<varchar text>"
```

e.g:

```
10.03.2016 07:40:38: blacksheep (127.0.0.1:54444) #865 "(this can have text
over several lines 
without ending marker"
10.03.2016 07:40:38: blacksheep (127.0.0.1:54444) #865 "A new line, just one without \n"
```

So I am starting with the following but I am stuck now with how to get the lines with `\n` into the string. How can this be solved the right way without unnecessary steps like splitting several times and how can I define where a complete line (even if it's having some `\n` within) stops?

With `fin.ignore(80, '\n');`, `\n`s are being ignored, but this implicates that I will only have one line... Short text before # and a very large string after :-|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string str, char seperator) {
   std::vector<std::string> result;
   std::string::size_type token_offset = 0;
   std::string::size_type seperator_offset = 0;
   while (seperator_offset != std::string::npos) {
      seperator_offset = str.find(seperator, seperator_offset);
      std::string::size_type token_length;
      if(seperator_offset == std::string::npos) {
         token_length = seperator_offset;
      } else {
         token_length = seperator_offset - token_offset;
         seperator_offset++;
      }
      std::string token = str.substr(token_offset, token_length);
      if (!token.empty()) {
         result.push_back(token);
      }
      token_offset = seperator_offset;
   }
   return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   std::fstream fin("input.dat");
   while(!fin.eof()) {
      std::string line;
      getline(fin, line, ';');
      fin.ignore(80, '\n'); 
      std::vector<std::string> strs = split(line, ',');
      for(int i = 0; i < strs.size(); ++i) {
         std::cout << strs[i] << std::endl;
      }
   }
   fin.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Regards
Blacksheep

Comment: Could you please give us the format of `<date> <time> <username>(<ip:port>) <uuid>`? What is the ending marker? I don't see `<uuid>` in the sample.

Comment: Please see the second code quotebox. This contains an example log. The uuid is right after the hash. And it's exactly my problem that the log des not have any reliable ending marker instand of the ending doublequote surrounding the varchar Text. Thanks.

Comment: There is not a hash. I can see date and time, username host:port but then I see #id followed by "text". Please point out where the hash and uuid is. Exact values from your sample, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no canned C++ library function for swallowing input like that. `std::getline` reads the next line of text, up until the next newline character (by default). That's it. `std::getline` does not do any further examination on the input, beyond that.

I will suggest the following approach for you.

- Initialize a buffer representing the entire logical line just read.
- Read the next line of input, using `std::getline`(), and append the line to the input buffer.
- Count the number of quote characters in the buffer.
- Is the number of quotes even? Stop. If the quote character count is odd, append a newline to the buffer, then go back and read another line of input.

Some obvious optimizations are possible here, of course, but this should be a good start.

Comment: Yes, that could be a good starting. Usually the lines having \n are not ending with doublequotes but to be on the safe side i will check each line if it starts with a date or not  thanks a lot